# Frozen chat room

Tags: support, chat

Sorry for posting that on Meta, but I don't see any other way to reach out:

Currently our chat room is frozen for inactivity. That means:

- no announcements of new questions
- room will be auto-deleted soon

May I propose one of our mods "thaws" it (a normal user can't)? And: Can anything be done to prevent such freezes from happening again *on our main chat room*? IMHO such rooms should be excluded from freezes, as they are often the only place to reach out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.

There isn't any way to mark a room as not-freezable (see [Antifreeze for Chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165206/antifreeze-for-chat-rooms)), although I wish there was. Probably the best way to take care of this is a flag on the main site.

Or, ideally, we would actually use the room ;)

Comment: Thanks, Undo! If nobody objects, your last suggestion would be a working solution – with a tiny addition: if you see the last message is older than 24h, just send a "good (morning|day|afternoon|evening|night)" message to keep it alive (whoever sees that – who comes next doesn't need to care anymore then :)

Answer (score 4):

[There is a rule to avoid freezing the main chat room of a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130472/dont-freeze-a-chatroom-soon-after-a-mod-has-unfrozen-it/130504#130504), but it doesn't identify any particular room as the main room. Rather, the *last* remaining unfrozen room of a site will not be frozen.

The [Duga room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22668/duga-software-recommendations) is considered an active room since a normal user talks there fairly often. The normal user is actually a bot, but that's an external bot, so Stack Exchange doesn't know that it isn't a human and considers the room to be active. Our main chatroom has posts from RSS feeds, but those are identified as automatic and don't count towards freeze-preventing activity.

Does anyone pay attention to the activity from Duga? If not maybe it should be shut down. If people do pay attention, maybe it should be in the main room. Or the bot could be reengineered to provide a RSS feed instead of directly posting into the room, then the Duga room would have been frozen (which doesn't prevent the RSS feed from posting).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Gilles! I actually didn't even know the Duga room to exist – always thought "the other one" was our primary (and only) chat room. Of course we could have a "keep-alive-bot" (if that's all he does) – though that might risk users to ping it for attention :)